# How to obtain a specific document from Firebase in Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js

**How to obtain and display a single document from a list of documents from Firebase Firestore data**?

I’m able to grab the collection of documents and display the information but I just want to grab one so I can display it elsewhere without duplicating multiple elements with data.

Firebase example:

```
DocID: title - “Pizza”
DocID: title - “Pancakes”
DocID: title - “Cereal”
```

Vue template example:

```
H1-tag {{display the title of Pizza here}} h1tag
```

Is there a way to do this without having multiple h1 elements with different titles?

Comment: Do you want to only get the doc with title = Pizza or you want to take a random doc among the three ones? Are the titles unique across the collection?

Answer (score 0):

`DocID: title - “Pizza” DocID: title - “Pancakes” DocID: title - “Cereal”`

One of the options:

Must be an array or convert to an array. And then receive data from it.

```js
items: [
        {
          title: 'Pizza',
          price: ''
        },
        {
          title: 'Pancake',
          price: ''
        },
        {
          title: 'Cereal',
          price: ''
        }
      ]
```

`<h1>{{items[0].title}}</h1>`

**vue3**

```js
setup () {            
            const items = ref([])

            db.collection('products').onSnapshot((snapshotChange) => {
                items.value = []
                snapshotChange.forEach((doc) => {
                    items.value.push({
                        key: doc.id,
                        title: doc.data().title,
                        price: doc.data().price                        
                    })
                })
            })

            return {                
                items                
            }
        }
```